# Reorganize model array to reflect table row drag and drops

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, algebra

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out a way to reorganize my model array when the user commits a drag and drop on an `NSTableView`. They can currently select one or more row, and drop them before or after any row in the table.

I'm given an `IndexSet` containing the rows of the table that were dragged. I'm also given a single `destinationRow` representing the destination of where those rows will be placed.

So for example, the original model looks like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

And the user drags rows `1` and `2` to after `3`...

Then I need to update my array to look like this: `[0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5]`

Any ideas on how to efficiently achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I'd been approaching the problem the wrong way.

I was trying to think of how to swap elements with their indexes, when all I really needed to do was use the built in functions .`remove(at:)` and `.insert(obj, at:)`

That allowed me to reorganize the array quite simply.

Comment: That's correct, but calculating the target index becomes more complex, when you have a dicontinuing selection around the (original) target. I. e. dragging 1, 2, 5 behind 3.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Is this a question or can you give us the solution?

Comment: It is a hint. I wrote the solution in one of my books as example. However, knowing of the problem it should be easy to deal with it: Subtract from the target index the count of items with an index smaller than the target index.

Comment: Solution: `let newRow = destinationRow - indexSet.count(in: 0...destinationRow)`